# How to solve ionic datetime window color issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to implement https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#datetime
in ionic project and I added it on my template successfully and problem is month day year displaying  in white color and background also white in color so we are unable to view any thing, how to solve this issue?

html code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date of birth</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="event.month"></io$
</ion-item>
```

.ts code

```
 public event = {
month: '1990-02-19',
}
```

result view using Mozilla Firefox:

[image]

but no problem in Google Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the template:

```html
<ion-item class="force-black-font">
      <ion-label>Date of birth</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="event.month"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

and then add this to your css:

```css
.force-black-font {
  color: black !important;
}
```